# Write on Excel file while it is open by another user

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, epplus

I'm trying to edit an opened excel file (by another user in a shared network) in order to make some changes to it and save it back. But when I try to open the file I get the following error :

```
Message=The process cannot access the file      
'Y:\COMMON\SharedFolders\Export.xlsx', because it is being used by another process.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
    à System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    à System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
    à System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
    à System.IO.File.InternalReadAllBytes(String path, Boolean checkHost)
    à System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(String path)
    à OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.ReadFile()
    à OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.ConstructNewFile(Stream stream, String password)
    à OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage..ctor(FileInfo newFile)
```

By the way, I'm using the [EPPLUS](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library.

Comment: Well you obviously can't use a file that is being locked by another process...You might try to make a copy, make changes to it and wait till the original isn't locked anymore.

Comment: Is it possible to kill the user process ?

Comment: In theory sure, if you have access to his machine and correct permissions to do so, but I guess it will be kinda tricky over the network.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-HP010096833.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That being said you can look into some "source-safe" solution (like svn, sharepoint or google docs). You can also implement some "poor man" source safe yourself - i.e. small web application that will act as proxy over file system & will allow you to upload file, list folder, download files.

Other option would be to delay update to date when no-one will be accessing that file.

Answer (score 0):

Google allow multiple edit at the same time... maybe you should try to move that file there if possible.

Comment: It's a confidential file

Comment: There is control security on those cloud drive solution, like GDrive, so share only with specific person.
Of course, you need to trush the cloud for security, like gmail, hotmail and so on.
Anyway, I know that inside an enterprise it could be hard to implement. 
Good luck